# Arduino Uno + aRest + ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

So, I can use the aRest library to program to the ESP8266 standalone, but if I have the ESP8266 connected to the Arduino Uno, can I still use the aRest library? Or will this no longer work?  I am trying to send a request to the Arduino unit that will toggle a pin to turn on/off via the aRest library.  Thanks!

aRest can be found here: https://github.com/marcoschwartz/aREST

Comment: Please edit your question. It currently needs more detail on what you are trying to achieve and is too broad and unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try it? :)

In overview of GitHub repo, first sentence, it says: "A simple library that implements a REST API for **Arduino** & the ESP8266 WiFi chip." Next paragraph confirms it.

Comment: It is for the chip itself, not when the chip is connected to the Arduino unit.  The chip can be a standalone microcontroller

Comment: If it works on Arduino unit itself, it can be made to work with ESP8266 for sure, right? Maybe just there it no ready code, you need to edit a bit.

Comment: It doesn't work on the Arduino itself, it works with a wifi chip like the CC3000 connected to the Arduino, or the ESP8266 standalone.  Haven't seen anything that has it using an ESP8266 connected to an Arduino